# Need help creating border around document.write statements in a function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, colors, border

So I want whatever color (red, blue, or green) the person types in to become the border color that shows up around the document.write statements in the thirdPrompt.

I know I can do this in the Body without a function, but I was wondering if there is any way to get it to work after the thirdPrompt happens. Thanks!

```
<style type = "text/css">

    div.red {border-style:solid;border-width:1em; border-color:red; padding:1em;}

    div.blue {border-style:solid;border-width:1em; border-color:blue; padding:1em;}

    div.green {border-style:solid;border-width:1em; border-color:green; padding:1em;}

    div.black {border-style:solid;border-width:1em; border-color:black; padding:1em;}

</head>
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function firstPrompt()
        {
        document.bgColor=('gray')
        var background
            {
                borderColor = window.prompt ("Please enter the border color you want: red, green, or blue.");

                if (borderColor == "red" || borderColor == "green" || borderColor == "blue")
                    {
                    enterWord = window.prompt ("Enter a word in the text field, all alphabetic characters.");
                    secondPrompt();
                    }
                else
                {
                    window.alert ("You didn't enter a valid color (red, green, blue), border color will be black!");
                    borderColor = ('black');
                    enterWord = window.prompt ("Enter a word in the text field, all alphabetic characters.");
                    secondPrompt();
                }
            }
        }



        function secondPrompt()
        {
        if (/[^0-9A-Z" "]/.test(enterWord))
            {
            enterLetter = window.prompt ("Enter a letter in the text field below.")
            findVowels();
            }
        else
        {
            window.alert ("Sorry you entered an invalid word (" + enterWord + ") please re-enter!");
            enterWord = window.prompt ("Enter a word in the text field, all alphabetic characters.");
            secondPrompt();
        }
        }



        function findVowels()
            {
                totalVowels = 0;

                for (i = 0; i < enterWord.length; i++)
                    {
                    if (enterWord.charAt(i).match(/[a-z]/) !=null)
                    {
                    if (enterWord.charAt(i).match (/[aeiou]/))
                        {

                            totalVowels++;
                        }
                    }
                    }
                thirdPrompt();
                return totalVowels;
            }



    function thirdPrompt()
        {
            if (/[^0-9A-Z" "]/.test(enterLetter) && (enterLetter.length < 2))
            {
                document.write("<div class = "+borderColor+">");

                document.write ("<h2>Word Checker</h2>");
                document.write ("<h2>" + Date() + "</h2>");
                document.write ("<br />" + "The word you entered was "+ "<strong>" + enterWord + "</strong>" + ". <br/>");
                document.write ("It contains " + enterWord.length + " character(s)." + "<br/>");
                document.write ("It contains " + totalVowels + " vowel(s)." + "<br />");
                document.write ("String '" + enterWord + "' contains the letter '" + enterLetter + "' at position ");
                document.write('</div>');

                document.bgColor = ("gray");


            }

            else
            {
                window.alert ("You entered an invalid character (" + enterLetter + ") please re-enter");
                secondPrompt();
            }

        }

</script>

<body onload = "firstPrompt();">

    <h2>
        Word Checker
    </h2>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. In response to what do you want the color to be changed?

Comment: Put the whole lot in one big div. Give the div an id. then apply the border to the div(by id) at the end of the 3rd prompt code.

Comment: The style of your code example is very poor. For example, your style tag is closing after your head tag.

Comment: Nick is right, `</head>` is invalid inside a style tag. Not even removing it and quoting the class makes the original code work though, I'm investigating it still.

Comment: Please don't wipe your question once you have an answer. We're trying to build a resource that will help many other visitors in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
document.write("<div class = "+borderColor+">");
```

With this:

```
document.write("<div style='border:solid 2px "+borderColor+"; padding:1em;'>");
```

Where `solid` is the [`border-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-style) and `2px` the [`border-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-width). Adapt to your needs.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ezKvp/)

---

### Edit:

Found the problem with the original code, your function is set to run in the `onload` event (after the page has fully loaded) and you're executing a `document.write` which overwrites the whole document (including the CSS) when executed after the page is loaded. More info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1331430).

If you remove the function from the body's `onload` event and simply call it during the page load it'll work as expected:

```
<body>
    <h2>
        Word Checker
    </h2>
    <script>
        firstPrompt();
    </script>
</body>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jppcU/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, I have been stuck on that for ages! New to javascript :D

Comment: Oh wait I figured it out from your post. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1781453 I adapted the question to include the padding. Ok no problem. `=]`

Comment: @user1781453 I found the problem with the original code, by the way. Updated my answer if you'd like to know why it wasn't working before. `=]`